# Why does my laptop freeze and restart unexpectedly on its own at random times?

Tags: 14.04, freeze, restart

I have Ubuntu 14.04, I recently had windows 8.1 which came installed with my dell inspiron 15 amd laptop. I decided I wanted ubuntu so i ran it off of a flash drive and replaced windows with it, now everything works fine for a little while before it freezes for about 5 seconds before restarting, any help?

Comment: Run `ubuntu-drivers devices` to check if your laptop needs a proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: Here are the results I got http://prntscr.com/6jkodt

Comment: The model name and number is i3541-5001BLK, the processor is a amd 6310 quad core with 8 gigs of ram, and here is the results from the command http://prntscr.com/6jl9wv

Comment: reposted from a comment by Johnny Moore: I ran into a problem [prntscr.com/6jltq8](http://prntscr.com/6jltq8)

Answer (score 0):

Once I ran into the same problem, Ubuntu 14.04 restarted on its own. The reason why that was happening was that the ISO from which I installed it became corrupt when transfered to the USB stick I meant to use. It could install Ubuntu, but not properly. My solution was trying a **new download and doing a fresh install again using a different stick**.

Hope that helps, although you probably had thought that already!

Comment: I downloaded the ISO from the official Ubuntu website, if its corrupted from there, than where should I download it?

Comment: I also downloaded it from the official website, but that's not the point. I think my issue occurred locally, when transferring the file to the USB stick I used. So I am not suggesting trying a non official website (of course, I don't doubt the safety of the official Ubuntu). I meant **using a different USB stick, or a CD.**